# How do I write out a text file in C# with a code page other than UTF-8?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I want to write out a text file.

Instead of the default UTF-8, I want to write it encoded as ISO-8859-1 which is code page 28591. I have no idea how to do this...

I'm writing out my file with the following very simple code:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(myfilename))
{
    sw.WriteLine("my text...");
    sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(myfilename, FileMode.Create), Encoding.WhateverYouWant))
{    
    sw.WriteLine("my text...");     
}
```

An alternate way of getting your encoding:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

using (var sw  = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"c:\myfile.txt", FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"))) {
    sw.WriteLine("my text...");             
}
```

Check out the docs for the StreamWriter constructor.

Comment: Can "whatever I want" be a code page number or...?  the autocomplete on the function in MS Visual C# isn't giving me an "iso-8859-1" option... just the UTF8, UTF16, etc...

Comment: Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")

Comment: What's wrong with just: `using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(myfilename), Encoding.WhateverYouWant)) { }`

Answer (score 35):

Simple!

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, text, Encoding.GetEncoding(28591));
```

Comment: It can be even more simple: File.WriteAllLines(path, lines, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: @LevZ: Excellent addition - I suspect it wasn't available when I wrote the answer 9 years ago :)

Comment: @LevZ: `UTF-8` may not always work, and you might need to use a specific 8-bit ASCII encoding. `UTF-8` is liable to save the file as UNICODE, so best to check carefully.

Comment: @AlainD please clarify what you mean with "may not always work"

Comment: Load any 8-bit file saved with ISO-8859-X encoding using `File.ReadAllText`. Write back to disk with `File.WriteAllText`. ASCII characters > 127 are liable to be changed (example: `Š`). File size changes if the original had strictly 8-bit ASCII encoding. One of my example files went from 133kB to 201kB and BEFORE != AFTER. The point is, if reading a file know how the original file was created, and know how the output file will be consumed. `28591` and `UTF-8` are good, but may be inappropriate in some situations.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your StreamWriter with FileStream, this way:

```
string fileName = "test.txt";
string textToAdd = "Example text in file";
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"); //Or any other Encoding

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs, encoding))
    {
        writer.Write(textToAdd);
    }
}
```

[Look at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this

```
 switch (EncodingFormat.Trim().ToLower())
    {
        case "utf-8":
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, new UTF8Encoding(false), convertToCSV(result, fileName)));
            break;
        case "utf-8+bom":
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, new UTF8Encoding(true), convertToCSV(result, fileName)));
            break;
        case "ISO-8859-1":
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, ASCIIEncoding.Convert(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), convertToCSV(result, fileName)));
            break;
        case ..............
    }
```

Answer (score -5):

Change the Encoding of the stream writer.  It's a property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.encoding.aspx

So:

```
sw.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(28591);
```

Prior to writing to the stream.