# .NET Write Text File for Unix System (Icinga or Nagios)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linux, unix

I want to create a file with VB.NET and I want to use this file for a Icinga or Nagios configuration.

How to create a file in correct Unix format with encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already explained: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-to-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8). Just detect what encoding you want receive finally.