# File encoding doesn't work

Tags: c#, file, encoding, streamwriter

In my code

```
string[] Lines = reactor.GetMergedLines();
string fileName = "foo.bar";
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew), Encoding.GetEncoding(28605));
foreach (string line in Lines)
{
    sw.WriteLine(line);
}
sw.Close();
```

the file, which gets created is not encoded with the given codepage. Lines is filled with strings out of an iso-8859-1-file. I tried it with the code page number `Encoding.GetEncoding(28605)`, it's name `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-15")` and with `File.WriteAllLines(fileName, Lines, Encoding.GetEncoding(28605))` instead of StreamWriter. But if I take a look at the file with cygwin `file -bi [filename]`, it tells me, the encoding would be "us-ascii". Also, some characters aren't encoded properly and replaced by question marks.

[How to write out a text file in C# with a code page other than utf-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-to-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8) didn't helped, as you can see.

What is the problem?

Comment: `some characters aren't encoded properly and replaced by question marks` how do you know that? Is the tool you use to look at the file capable of setting the desired code page? `file` has no way of guessing the file is ISO-8859-15 encoded, there is no metadata. You need to read the file with a ISO-8859-15 decoding to be able to say is properly saved or not.

Comment: I tried it with notepad++ and set the encoding to ISO-8859-15. Also with other text viewers. Still question marks. And those aren't the standard chars for characters with unknown encoding.

Comment: Is the text you're saving a valid ISO-8859-15 text?

Comment: @RemusRusanu What do you mean by that? How can it be invalid?

Comment: [ISO-8859-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-15) is a "8-bit single-byte coded graphic character set". It has a limited set of characters it can encode, about 255 of them. Your C# `string` are Unicode, with several tens of thousands of valid [code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point). Obviously not all C# string values have a valid single-byte code page equivalent.

Comment: Okay. I checked that. Every character in the source file, which are also the characters in `Lines`, are valid for ISO-8859-1 and ISO-8859-15. It contains only characters of an intersection of both code pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use other overloads of `Encoding.GetEncoding` to handle all cases when an Unicode character can't be converted to your target code page. More information on this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencoding).
The same could be achieved if you explicitly set the `Encoding.EncoderFallback` property ([link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.encoderfallback)).

For example you can use the following to throw an exception every time when conversion of one Unicode character fails:

```
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(28605, EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback, DecoderFallback.ExceptionFallback);
```

Note: The default `EncoderFallback` is `System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback` which produces question marks for unknown code points.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helps troubleshooting my problem. But the error message I got was actually more confusing. I wrote to the file line by line and got an exception at a particular line with about 10 characters. But the message was, that there was an error at index 262. How can that be?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The actual writing with `StreamWriter` is buffered, so the index you see is within this buffer. You can control the buffer size with another constructor overload. You can also control the flushing mode with the Boolean property `AutoFlush`. This means that this `StreamWriter` actually writes its data only if the buffer is full (`false`) or when any of the overridden `Write` methods are called (`true`). The default is `false` but in any case the buffer is also flushed when `StreamWriter` will be disposed and **not** when it is finalized by the GC.