# HttpWebRequest Encoding - UTF-8

Tags: c#, utf-8, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to fetch some data from a web page but i faced character problem. The web page is in utf-8 format and in multi-language, in this case, i can fetch the english based senteces/datas without any problem but for italian, spanish and turkish data, i'm getting wrong characters.

when i check the saved html file, for text coding it says : windows-1254

As you can see in my method i tried to solve the problem by using in streamreader ;

```
    Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Encoding.Default
    Encoding.UTF8
```

Httpwebrequest :

```
string postdata = "username" + usern + "&pass=" + pass";
byte[] bytes = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(postdata);
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.*******.com/login.php");
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;
request.CookieContainer = cont;
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
request.CookieContainer.Add(cok);
request.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";                  
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/2.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.GetRequestStream().Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

HttpWebResponse response = null;
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();          
StreamReader _str2 = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
 string html = _str2.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText("login_response.html", html);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your error is not on the fetching, but on the writing of the new file, so instead of using `File.WriteAllText`, you perhaps should look at:

[How to write out a text file in C# with a code page other than utf-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373365/how-to-write-out-a-text-file-in-c-sharp-with-a-code-page-other-than-utf-8)

i.e.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(myfilename, FileMode.Create), Encoding.WhateverYouWant))
{    
    sw.WriteLine("my text...");     
}
```

(example from that page).

--- EDIT :

You can do the same on File.WriteAllText apparently: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143376(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, you are totally right.i was focused too much on request and response parts. thank you again.